# How to align Google Custom Search box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, uisearchbar, google-custom-search

I want to align google custom search box to the left of my webpage. I'm using a website builder called imxprs. I use this code for my custom search box.

```html
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '013012496897428955507:iauh0vbao98';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

How can I do this?
Optional: And if anybody is using imxprs, do you know how to make search box on the same line with the H1 of the blog element like in the picture>>
[Like this, I photoshoped it!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wjsz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is wrap the `<gcse:search></gcse:search>` tags in a div and you can then apply properties on that div to meet your criteria like would do during normal course of development. Take a look at the code snippet

```css
#searchContainer {
width: 49%;
float: right;
display: inline-block;
}

#heading {
display: inline-block;
width: 49%;
}

.container {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '013012496897428955507:iauh0vbao98';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<div class="container">
<h1 id="heading">Articles</h1>
<div id="searchContainer">
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Here's how I am getting it. https://imgur.com/a/8L6Eb

Comment: Make sure to wrap the css in style tags. Try running the code snippet in stackoverflow itself. The basic idea is to wrap the custom search tags into a parent div. Then you can apply the styles to that parent div

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know if that word is enough. Really thank you! :D

Comment: Glad to be of help! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
    var cx = '013012496897428955507:iauh0vbao98';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
```

```css
.container{
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
}

h1{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1> Hello, World </h1>
<div class="container">
  <gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```